# Add a suffix to all image URLs (File URL)

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to add a suffix having certain values (such as min123) to all image URLs on my WordPress website getallnumber.com. The images are located in "/wp-content/uploads/year/month/". After adding the value the URL should be /wp-content/uploads/year/month/image.min123.png. I tried some pieces of codes including the sanitize code but there is no lock. Please help me out!

```
function sa_sanitize_special_chars ($filename) {
$f=remove_accents( $filename );
return 'min123-'.$f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below code snippet in your active theme's functions.php file -

```
// wp media name suffix on upload
function modify_wp_handle_upload_prefilter( $file ) {
    if( isset( $file['name'] ) ) {
        $fileinfo = pathinfo( $file['name'] );
        if( $fileinfo && isset( $fileinfo['filename'] ) && isset( $fileinfo['extension'] ) ) {
            $suffix = 'min123'; // your suffix goes here
            $name = $fileinfo['filename'] . '.' . $suffix . '.' . $fileinfo['extension'];
            $file['name'] = $name;
        }
    }
    return $file;
}
add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'modify_wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 99 );
```

Comment: Sadly, not working - https://prnt.sc/cwX72QhYAR9W   The url is same        https://www.getallnumber.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/Kallada-Travels-Contact-Number.png, Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Hello itzmekhokan. Do you need more info about codes in the theme of my site?

Comment: @user31225 try to add a new image and check the url of uploaded one.

Comment: @user31225 This above code will work only for new media uploads, for existing all images I'm sorry to say this will not work. Its need some more extra efforts and coding to do so. Feel free to contact me if needed from my profile.

Comment: okay. It is working for new media upload.  thank you so much